# replace single line javascript comments with multiline style comments in Notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, replace, comments, notepad++

I would like to use Notepad++ to search a javascript file or a html file containing some javascript and replace all single line comments with a multiline style comment.

For example `// some comment goes here` to be replaced with `/* some comment goes here */`

Using Notepad++ search and replace with Regular Expression selected with  `(//.*)(\r\n)` for search and `\/*\1\*/\r\n` kinda works.

Problems:

1. It only finds `// some comment goes here` if there is at least one space before the // it will not find it if there is a tab before it, or at the start of a line or if there is a letter/number before it.  I could workaround that by first doing a global non regular expression search replace to replace all occurrences of `//` with `space //`
2. `// some comment goes here` is replaced with `/*// some comment goes here*/` that is the two forward slashes are not replaced.  I can workaround this afterwards by doing a global non regular expression search to replace all occurrences of `/*//` with `/*`.
3. The javascript may be in a html file, in which case somewhere in the file there is likely to be something like `http://msdn.microsoft.com/` clearly I would not like this to be replaced with `http:/*msdn.microsoft.com/*/`  I could workaround this in advance by replacing all `://` with say `:/ZZZ/` where ZZZ is some escaping method and then afterwards replacing `:/ZZZ/` with `://`
4. There will be problems with the likes of `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`  I guess that I will have to look after these manually.

This is not really a Notepad++ problem.  I am sure that I would have the same difficulties using any regular search and replace system.

All suggestions gratefully received.

Thank you for taking the time to read this

Comment: What about: `myString = ' // ';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Quick way***

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\s)//([^\n\r]*)
```

Replace with:

```
/\*$1\*/
```

***Explanatory way***

1 - *Double slashes* **//** weren't going to replace, because you had them in that capturing group. So you'll capture and replace them again.

2 - Most of the time there is nothing but a space or a newline (\n) before comments begin. I included this as a lookbehind to ensure. By this way, *URLs* and *DOCTYPE* won't get touched.

** I don't confirm this searching and replacing method, however it may work with most cases.*

### Update

Take care of settings. You should have you cursor at the very beginning of the file content.

[image]

Then do a *Replace All*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Revo. Notepad++ has some odd behaviour, it seems to intermittently not find/replace the same \\ comment I will need further experimentation on this.  How can your regex be modified so that a non white space character in front of the \\ will still find the comment.  I have tried a period and that finds such a comment but also finds URLS and DOCTYPE but will not find a comment is there is a new line in front of it.please have a look at  http://regex101.com/r/xG4eQ5/2

Comment: @user1558796 When using online Regular Expression testers you have to use `g` flag to see all occurrences, [Check it](http://regex101.com/r/xG4eQ5/3). Also in Notepad++ there is no need to escape slashes. I updated my answer with pictures.

Comment: thanks revo, you have put quite a lot of work into this.  If I have a `//` type comment that is butting up to a  `;` or an other character then the search replace will not work.  Is there any workaround for that?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user1558796 Would you give an example in which it doesn't work?

Comment: revo, in this http://regex101.com/r/xG4eQ5/5 the line is not found `;//comment` but `//comment` is.

Comment: @user1558796 In the regex I made a lookbehind to check only for spaces before comments begin `//`. If you wanna take care of other characters URLs and DOCTYPE will change accordingly! However `(?<=\s|;)//([^\n\r]*)` this will work for comments that preceded by any spaces or semi-colons `;`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for regex, use a parser instead. Have a look at: [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) for example.

Comment: M42, Esprima is very interesting, I had not heard of it before.  However I did not find a way to  use it to change // comments into /* */ comments.  Thank you