# Replace wrong xml-comments with Regex

Tags: regex

I am dealing with a bunch of xml files that contain one-line-comments like this: `// Some comment`.
I am pretty sure that xml comments look like this: `<!-- Some comment -->` 
I would like to use a regular expression in the Atom editor to find and replace all wrong comment syntax.

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26344512/4457885), the comment can be found with `(?<=\s)//([^\n\r]*)` and replaced with something like `<!--$1-->`. There must be an error somewhere since clicking replace button leaves the comment as is, instaed of replacing it. Actually I can't even replace it with a simple character.
The find and replace works with a different regex in the "Find" field:
*Find:* `name.*`
*Replace:* `baloon`

Is there anything I can write in the "Find" and "Replace" field to achieve this transformation?

Comment: If it is Atom, the problem might be with the lookbehind. Try just `//([^\n\r]+)` and replace wih `<!--$1-->`. If you need to check for the space, try `(^|\s)//([^\n\r]+)` => `$1<!--$2-->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom editor search and replace currently does not support lookbehind constructs, like `(?<=\s)`. To "imitate" it, you may use a capturing group with an alternation between start of string, `^`, and a whitespace, `\s`.

So, you may use

*Find What*: `(^|\s)//([^\n\r]+)`
*Replace With*: `$1<!--$2-->`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sz2bNq/1). **NOTE** `\s` may match newlines, so you may probably want to use `(^|[^\S\r\n])//([^\n\r]+)` to avoid matching across line breaks.

If you do not need to check for a whitespace, just remove that first capturing group and use a mere:

*Find What*: `//([^\n\r]+)`
*Replace With*: `<!--$1-->`

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sz2bNq/2).